# Find $\iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n} d\mathbf{\sigma}$ with $\Sigma$ the following surface:

Tags: calculus, integration

$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(2x,-3y,z)$, $\Sigma$ consists of the curved surface $x^2+y^2=1$ of a cylinder, enclosed between $z=0$ and $z=x+2$.

My attempt:

I first thought of the divergence theorem, but then the answer would be $0$ which is not correct. **(The answer: $\mathbf{-2\pi}$)**. So my first question is: why can't I apply the divergence theorem?

I need to find the flux through a surface which consists of three smooth surfaces. Do I just calculate the flux through the three of them separately?

For the upper surface ($z=x+2$, with underlying region the disk $x^2+y^2 \le 1$), I found $2\pi$. For $z=0$, I found $0$. But then I'm stuck with the curved surface of the cylinder. How can I parameterize it?

Thanks.

Comment: to apply divergence theorem, you have to use the whole boundary of the cyllinder (the integral over the top and bottom parts)

Comment: Yeah apply divergence theorem to get the volume integral then take away the top and bottom parts (surface integrals)

Comment: You can parametrize the lateral surface of this cylinder by the angle and th elevation:
$$(x,y,z) = (\cos\phi,\sin \phi, t), \qquad \phi\in[0,2\pi), \quad t\in[0,2+\cos\phi]$$
When integrating, just remember to first integrate over $t$, as the limit for $t$ depends on $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence theorem says that
$$\int_\Sigma {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma+\int_{\rm top} {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma+\int_{\rm bottom} {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma=\int_D{\rm div}({\bf F})\>{\rm dvol}\ ,$$
where $D$ is the skewly cut cylindrical volume with plane top and bottom surfaces, and ${\bf n}$ points to the outside of $D$. Since you easily compute ${\rm div}({\bf F})\equiv0$ you can say that
$$\int_\Sigma {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma=-\int_{\rm top} {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma-\int_{\rm bottom} {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\>d\sigma\ .$$
As you have already computed the top and bottom integrals you are therefore done. You don't have to set up a parametric representation of the cylindrical part of $D$'s boundary.